# How to reduce CPU utilization at startup time of .Net 5 application?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, .net-core, containers, .net-5

I know that applications use high CPU when application starts, this is normal but there are really high differences between startup time usage and standart time usage.

My application runs with Docker and Kubernetes and also, is a .Net 5 application.

Is there any way to reduce CPU utilization at the startup time?

---

---

***You can see the differences at the below picture:***

[image]

---

---

***Docker file:***

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal AS publish
WORKDIR /src
COPY src ./
RUN dotnet restore "API/API.csproj"
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish "API/API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish \ 
    --no-restore

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-focal AS final

# Install the agent
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget ca-certificates gnupg \
&& echo 'deb http://apt.newrelic.com/debian/ newrelic non-free' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/newrelic.list \
&& wget https://download.newrelic.com/548C16BF.gpg \
&& apt-key add 548C16BF.gpg \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y newrelic-netcore20-agent

WORKDIR /app
ENV CORECLR_ENABLE_PROFILING=1
COPY --from=publish /app/publish ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "API.dll"]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to reduce CPU utilization at the startup time?

The quick answer is no, since your application boots and uses this CPU, I assume once the boot is over the CPU usage is reduced might be because the initial process has finished and the required resources are now in memory.

I suggest verifying if the problem is in your code by running a clean .Net image and comparing the usage.

---

The only thing you can control is the PODs resource

[image]

Image credit: https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-limits-requests/

Comment: Might it be related to .Net docker image(5.0-focal) or any packages which are used by app? Thanks.

Comment: I know that mean of Limit&Request. My goal is to reduce the limit value to more low. That's the reason why I asked this question